# SVG image flickers on iOS 13.3/XS when animated using SMIL. In Safari or Chrome. No difference

Tags: ios, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

Animation works great on all desktop browsers as well as on iPhone 6 or 8 with iOS 12.

On iPhone XS with iOS 13.3 installed, periodic flickering is observed.

```
<style type="text/css">
  @-webkit-keyframes anim_pet {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); transform: rotate(-360deg); }
  }
  @keyframes anim_pet {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); transform: rotate(-360deg); }
  }
  .anim_pet {
    -webkit-animation: anim_pet 120s infinite linear;
    animation: anim_pet 120s infinite linear;
  }
</style>

<defs>
  <symbol id="symbol_pet">
    <path d="M0 0 L0.54 0.26 L0.79 1.29 L0.59 2.16 L-0.07 3.25 L-1.4 4.43 L-3.66 5.45 L-7.07 5.87 L-11.73 5.07 L-14.5 3.94 L-17.52 2.15 L-20.71 -0.43 L-23.96 -3.95 L-27.11 -8.57 L-29.97 -14.44 L-32.27 -21.69 L-33.7 -30.44 L-33.87 -40.75 L-32.32 -52.65 L-28.55 -66.09 L-21.95 -80.91 L-11.89 -96.83 L2.34 -113.45 L21.46 -130.14 L46.2 -146.11 L77.24 -160.3 L115.21 -171.39 L160.59 -177.78 L213.65 -177.54 L274.38 -168.44 L342.41 -147.92 L416.87 -113.12 L496.27 -60.93 "/>
  </symbol>
</defs>

<radialGradient id = "gra1" cx = "0%" cy = "0%" r = "424px" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop stop-color = "rgb(176,156,184)" offset = "0.2">
    <animate restart="never" attributeName="offset" calcMode="spline" values="0.2; 0.8"  keySplines="0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0" dur="8.0s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
  </stop>
</radialGradient>

<g id="flower" stroke="url(#gra1)">
  <g>
    <use class="anim_pet" xlink:href="#symbol_pet"/>
    <g transform="scale(-1,1)">
      <use class="anim_pet" xlink:href="#symbol_pet"/>
    </g>
  </g>

  <g transform="rotate(-30)">
    <use class="anim_pet" xlink:href="#symbol_pet"/>
    <g transform="scale(-1,1)">
      <use class="anim_pet" xlink:href="#symbol_pet"/>
    </g>
  </g>

  ...

  <g transform="rotate(-330)">
    <use class="anim_pet" xlink:href="#symbol_pet"/>
    <g transform="scale(-1,1)">
      <use class="anim_pet" xlink:href="#symbol_pet"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
```

[image]

Also, if I remove the gradient and fill the path, the flicker disappears.

```
... <g id="flower" stroke="blue"> ...
```

As I see it, this is a bug in the operating system, because it is observed both in Chrome and in Safari.

Or maybe I'm wrong?

Why exactly in the very latest iphone does this absurdity appear?

This is not in any of the browsers since 2012 :) At least as much as I support.